# Python - TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) but I gave 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new with Python so I tried some lines of code:

```
class loesung02(object):
    html = ""
    file1 = ""
    def __init__(self, html, file1):
        self.html = html
        self.file1 = file1
        print html + file1
```

i call it like that:

```
loesung02("aaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbb")
```

using the Python Shell

but I always get the ErrorMessage, so whats wrong?

Comment: The code you've posted works perfectly.  There must be more to this - please post a failing example.

Comment: The above code is valid. Could you try running it from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error message did you get? Your code run perfectly ok in my computer. I'm using python 2.7.1. Did you write that in a file and then run it or you write that in interpreter? If it is the latter, reinitialize or re-run your interpreter as there might be other variables that interfere with your code.